# Weird Result after a very memory consuming code

Tags: python-2.7

I recently ran a python code which basically finds whether a number is a prime number or not, but I input a very large number(6-7 digits) and after that whenever I input any number which has 7 in it, It shows the following.
[source-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DepoS.png)
I have already deleted the file and wrote same code again as well as tested in my PC's IDLE(VS Code) and a web-based also(Repl.it) but the problem remain. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with line#17, else condition is supposed to be for FOR LOOP, not for the if condition in line#13.

Change this code

```
for i in range(2,int(number1)/2):
    if (int(number1) % i) == 0:
        print "%s is not a prime number" % (number1)
        print i, "times" ,int(number1)/i, "is" ,int(number1)
        break
    else:
        print number1, "is a prime number"
```

to

```
for i in range(2,int(number1)/2):
    if (int(number1) % i) == 0:
        print "%s is not a prime number" % (number1)
        print i, "times" ,int(number1)/i, "is" ,int(number1)
        break
else:
    print number1, "is a prime number"
```